# File import callback not supported import "./IERC20.sol";

Tags: truffle, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, truffle-compile, interfaces

when I try to compile my contract I see errors like this :

DemirelToken.sol

https://eksiup.com/p/4z49413damc3

here's the code :

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract DemirelToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20Detailed("Gold", "GLD", 18) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

I get errors like this:

**node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "./IERC20.sol";
^--------------------^
,node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "../../math/SafeMath.sol";
^-------------------------------^
,node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "./IERC20.sol";**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the path in the imports:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract DemirelToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20Detailed("Gold", "GLD", 18) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have installed openzeppelin-solidity in your project

```
npm install openzeppelin-solidity
```

Your imports are then as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract DemirelToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20Detailed("Gold", "GLD", 18) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```